# Configure JaVers to create tables in a particular schema

Tags: postgresql, javers

When using JaVers, JaVers is creating its 4 tables in the public schema in Postgres (http://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/#connection-provider). I would like to configure it to save these tables in a new schema, example, AuditSchema. Is this possible to configure?

Comment: Unqualified tables are created in the first schema of the search_path. You could change the `search_path` of the Postgres user that JaVers uses and put that schema to the front.

Answer (score 2):

It's available now. Just set property `javers.sqlSchema=AuditSchema`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature, see https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/0e21d83ada5678eb9b396606dd6bc926ddf87b23/javers-persistence-sql/src/main/java/org/javers/repository/sql/schema/FixedSchemaFactory.java

It might be a good candidate for contribution to JaVers but all supported SQL dialects should be concerned (MySql, Postgres, MS SQL, H2, Oracle)